# How to pass sassOptions to the sass compiler with angular-cli

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I have a project set up with the Angular 2 CLI SCSS like this:

```
ng new myproject --style=scss
```

In the project now I can use scss (files ending with *.scss).
Actually it's really cool just out of the box. However usually you should be able to configure the settings. Something like this:

```
"sass":[
 {
  "browsers": [
    "last 10 versions"
  ],
  "cascade": false
 }
],
```

I presume I should find the settings in the angular-cli.json file, but I could not finde any settings.

What is the best practice for such a scenario?

Comment: @MertcanDiken could you please elaborate how that so-question and its answers relate to this specific problem? The link you posted explains how to use sass with angular-cli. The OP already knows that. The question now is how to pass options to the sass compiler. Please don't comment after only reading the headline of a question.